# Rails load yml file in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have made a yml file and placed in config/locals/models/en-US.yml .But I don't know how to load that file and get the data from that file to a view

en-US.yml

```
en-US:
  mysqlid:
    models:
      dashboard:
        one: Dashboard
        other: Dashboards
    attributes:
     dashboard:
        email: Email
        name: Name
        facebook_verified: Verified on Faceboo
```

Comment: Read the [Rails Internationalization (I18n) Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). It explains very thoroughly how to use locale configurations.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.i18n.load_path += 
  Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**/*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

More info there: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: anything further I have to do after loading this file

Comment: E.g. you can set default locale `I18n.default_locale = :en-US'. I've just edited my post. Please follow by provided link.

Comment: But even after placing the code How to use my yml data .And how it will cal the en-US.yml ?is it done automatically or I have to do something else also

Comment: If set 'en-US' as default locale then you'll be able to get your target data from en-US.yml file like this: t('mysqlid.models.dashboard.one')

Comment: For localization your models you should read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: what it is t('mysqlid.models.dashboard.one')  and where to set it?

Comment: How to call these attributes of yml in view?

Answer (score 1):

To get your yml data, you will need to use the `YAML` class to load the file.

To do this, you have to require `yaml` and then use it to load the data like below:

```
#controller:
require 'yaml'

def method
  @yaml_data = YAML.load_file('config/locales/models/en-US.yml ')
end
```

and the `yaml` data will be loaded into the `@yaml_data` instance variable, which you can now access from your view.

Comment: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/locals/models/en-US.yml
showing this error